# Google Messages Not Functioning Well

Tags: google-messages, samsung-galaxy-s-20

I've been having some troubles with Google messages the last few days, and by extension, the whole phone in general because of it. For full context, I have an unlocked Galaxy S20 5G that I bought in October 2020, running on Verizon's network, and up to date on Android 13.

It starts off with not being able to send or receive any messages to group chats with an iPhone in them. I can send and receive just fine from single threads to an iPhone, but groups will fail to send, and incoming messages go to the single thread and hang as an X with a spinning circle around it. Eventually, after a few hours, dozens of these messages go into their proper group, mostly very out of order. This has happened a number of times in the last few months, but it was particularly bad yesterday, so:

I tried to troubleshoot this problem more in depth. I rebooted and cleared the cache partition. I reset my network settings on the phone, cleared the cache on Messages, to no avail. I read that maybe the beta program I'm in for Messages pushed a bunk update, so I went to the playstore and opted out of the beta, and reinstalled the app. **The Play Store told me that I still had the beta app installed, even though I'm sure I didn't**. I cleared cache and data for the play store, and it properly said I just had the stable release of Messages. However, bad things are happening in the app.

[image]

The moment I begin scrolling, there are immediate blank conversation threads. The ones above and below start to repeat near endlessly, with the scroll bar getting quite large. Clicking those blank threads crashes the app. The conversations appear out of order.

If I wait in the app for a few minutes, it will finally reorganize, but the entire Messages app is very sluggish. It takes a noticeable amount of time to open the app, open conversations, certain conversations are not loading all their history, and it will hang on sending messages or hitting the back button to go back to all threads.

I attempted to clear the cache and data of Messages and have it rebuild, and it functions fine for about 5-10 minutes while it rebuilds, before eventually starting all the above symptoms again. The worst part of this is the battery drain. Android is not reporting any battery problems, but Messages is EATING battery life now, and the phone is noticeably warmer than usual.

What am I missing here? I have a feeling there are components of the beta version and stable version that are fighting for control here, but I can't dig deep enough to find anything like that. Short of backing all my stuff up and factory resetting the phone, I don't know what to do. Can anyone help?