# Will clearing Android Messages storage and cache cause lose of text messages?

Tags: samsung, sms, google-messages

I recently discovered that my [Android Messages app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) (version: `messages.android_20240109_01_RCO4.phone_dynamic`, updated on Jan 25, 2024) in my Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G (SM-G781V, Android 13) has been displaying text messages with an obnoxious line height.

I found [this solution](https://support.google.com/messages/thread/254820276?hl=en&msgid=255549336) on a Google support forum, but before I try it, I want to make sure I won't lose all my old text messages.

> Settings - applications - force stop then storage and cache - clear data then clear cache.

Comment: Possibly related issue: [Google Messages Not Functioning Well (on Galaxy S20 5G)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/255848/44325)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It won't delete your MMS/SMS (the conventional messages) in any case if you clear data of the default Messaging app. I'm not exactly sure about RCS chats but technically they should also be not cleared.
- A more safer approach would be

  1. Download another Messaging app (get a good 3rd part messaging app from Play Store)
  2. Make it the default messaging app
  3. See if all your messages (both SMS/MMS and RCS) are visible there
  4. Clear data of the original Messaging app you were refering to
  5. Once it's done, open it and make it the default Messaging app again
  6. After making sure all messages are back there, uninstall the third party app you installed

Comment: I followed these steps and found that my messages remained intact.